# How can I map a key combination to a certain character in WinXP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I use the United States-International keyboard layout for my computer. I want to map a special character to a key combination (for example, I want to type the interrobang by pressing `shift`+`!`+`?`) Is this even possible in Windows XP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://lifehacker.com/5883003/the-best-key-remapper-for-windows) they offer several key remapping and shortcut creating utilities.
One of them should do the job...